# difference between (int)num/2.0 and (int)(num/2.0)

Tags: c++

There's this expression that I can't really understand. I wrote a code where at some point i needed to assign to a float variable x the result of the expression (int)num/2.0 where num is an integer with value 305011. I found out that (int)num/2.0 gives me 152506 and (int)(num/2.0) gives me 152505 and when i try to sum them up 305010 comes out instead of 305011. Why?

Comment: `(int)num/2.0` would give you `152505.5`.

Comment: Have you checked the operator precedence? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that output is the same reason that this is true:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 305011;
    cout << num / 2; //152505
    cout << num / 2.0; //152506
}
```

For `cout << num / 2;` the compiler truncates the 0.5 because you're dividing an int by an int.

For `cout << num / 2.0;` the compiler rounds the 0.5 because the compiler actually automatically type-casted`num`,  divided by 2.0 and then recasted the result as an int.

In your case, you're controlling when the type casting occurs. Either before or after the division. When you type cast before the division, truncation occurs. When you type cast after the division, rounding occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Casting operator has higher precedence than divide operator.
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

(int)num/2.0 
First cast num to an int, then divide by 2.0

(int)(num/2.0)
Divide num by 2.0 then cast to an int